# JSON Java - Unexpected character (a) at position 59

Tags: java, json, parsing

I am trying to parse the following JSON. But getting exception please help.

```
{
  "method": "demo",
  "clazz": "storage",
  "params": [
    "",
    "LOGIN",
    "{"auth": {"tenantName": "AUTH_Tonny", "casauth": {"username": "Tonny", "tgt": "TGT-1876hkahaadcaweyfiowufssadsfsdf"}}}",
    "http://ipstorage.google.com"
  ]
}
```

Here is the Java Code:

```
        String tokenId = "";
        String message = "LOGIN";
        String url1 = "http://ipstorage.google.com";
        String authentication = "{\"auth\": {\"tenantName\": \"AUTH_" + test2.getUsername()
        + "\", \"casauth\": {\"username\": \""
        + test2.getUsername() + "\", \"tgt\": \""
        + test2.getPassword() + "\"}}}";
        String pp = "[\"" + tokenId + "\",\"" + message + "\",\""
                  + authentication + "\",\"" + url1 + "\"]";
        String msg1 = "{\"method\":\"demo\",\"clazz\":\"storage\",\"params\":" + pp + "}";
        System.out.println(msg1);
        JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(msg1);
        System.out.println("##");
        System.out.println(jo);
```

Output and exception which I am getting is:

```
    {"method":"demo","clazz":"storage","params":["","LOGIN","{"auth":
   {"tenantName": "AUTH_Tonny", "casauth": {"username": "Tonny", "tgt": "TGT - 
   1876 hkahaadcaweyfiowufssadsfsdf"}}}","http://ipstorage.google.com"]}
   Exception in thread "main" Unexpected character (a) at position 59.
    at org.json.simple.parser.Yylex.yylex(Unknown Source)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.nextToken(Unknown Source)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.t.g.i.e.utils.Test.main(Test.java:74)
```

Please help me out. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Replace `"{"auth"` with `"auth"`.

Comment: Not a valid json. Try https://jsonlint.com/ to validate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ to validate your json file.

```
{
"method": "demo",
"clazz": "storage",
"params": [
    "",
    "LOGIN",
    {
        "auth": {
            "tenantName": "AUTH_Tonny",
            "casauth": {
                "username": "Tonny",
                "tgt": "TGT-1876hkahaadcaweyfiowufssadsfsdf"
            }
        }
    },
    "http://ipstorage.google.com"
]
}
```

Comment: Thank you. My json format was not right, and after I cleaned it up, the code is running fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON format not right. Maybe You want JSON like this,

```
{
  "method": "demo",
  "clazz": "storage",
  "params": [
    "",
    "LOGIN",
    {"auth": {"tenantName": "AUTH_Tonny", "casauth": {"username": "Tonny", "tgt": "TGT-1876hkahaadcaweyfiowufssadsfsdf"}}},
    "http://ipstorage.google.com"
  ]
}
```

There no " before and after JSONObject. You can check your JSON Format with this tools.

https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Your java code should like this,

```
...
String pp = "[\"" + tokenId + "\",\"" + message + "\","
                  + authentication + ",\"" + url1 + "\"]";
...
```

to remove " in your JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Json validator to validate the string
and use a json parser libraries such as Gson or Jackson, it would automate a lot of your work and you don't need to code much to parse